# What do you name functions/variables/etc when you can't think of a good name?

Tags: naming, variables, functions

When you are defining a function/variable/etc and are not sure what to name it, what do you name it? How do you come up with a name?

If you use a ***temporary*** name as a place-card until you give it it's real name, what temporary name do you use?

---

#### update

I have been using things like `WILL_NAME_LATER`, `NEEDS_NAME`, or `TO_BE_NAMED`. I was hoping there was an adopted convention, I was actually hoping that if I used this adopted convention my IDE would highlight the name until I changed it.

Comment: Be careful about using all caps for variable names. By popular convention, it means a global variable.

Comment: @sunpech, I know, I use that naming convention for constants too. But I think the capitalization makes it stand out so I don't forget to rename it. I don't leave it named like that for long.

Comment: For all you people who are saying, you should never have a problem coming up with a name... Even *Jon Skeet* sometimes can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521893/whats-the-best-name-for-a-non-mutating-add-method-on-an-immutable-collection

Comment: @JohnIsaacks I think you should bold **temporary**. Too many people are reading this question and making code into something holy. Honestly, yes, you can write sloppy code ESPECIALLY when you're trying to push through to something more important. We're not etching code into stone here.

Comment: I guess the convention for something like this would be to add a TODO in the code, with the explanation of why you need to update it. Many tools can parse those TODOs and show a list of all things left to be done.

Comment: This is also a good question for Programmers.SE. I can't believe I'm the only one that's up-voted it thus far.

Comment: @Eduardo I use TODO: all the time, great recommendation.

Comment: I prefer thinking once again harder...

Comment: Whoah, temporary?? You're specifically writing code that you'll have to come back and fix later? What's the likelihood you'll move onto higher priority work and it'll get left behind?

Comment: It might not be something that's supposed to be used in the code. For exemple, you might have to log something, or split operations in parts to get a view from the debugger. Or you might have to give a fake user a fake name. I usually just go with chicken in those cases, as it's easy to find and remove.

Comment: I like using greek letters.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's nearly impossible to not be able to think of a name for an artifact you want to design. You may not like what name you come up with because it isn't concise or sexy, but if you think too hard, you'll end up with a poorly named artifact.

Let's say you have something that helps you construct objects, but you don't know this is typically called a factory. Just call it ObjectCreator. It sounds obtuse, but at least it's clear.

Let's say you have a dictionary that converts hostnames to IP addresses. Just go ahead and call it HostnamesToIpAddresses. Sure it's long, but it says exactly what it does.

The inability to come up with a name for something means you don't know what it is doing, which also means you have a greater problem before you.

Comment: I always want to slap people who complain about identifiers being too long (when they're only three or four words).  We should not be limited by our typing speed, and if we are, we should go look at [ABCD](http://gigliwood.com/abcd/) and learn to type!

Comment: +1 because of `"The inability to come up with a name for something means you don't know what it is doing"`. I think this really is an important point. Realizing this helps you find ambiguities and unclarity in code.

Answer (score 34):

I always try to give my variables and functions **great names**.

If I can't think of a great name, I'll settle for a **good name**.

If I can't come up with a good name, I'll use an **okay name**.

I have never, in 15 years of professional programming, been unable to come up with a decent name.

Comment: +1 for being, like, poetic.

Comment: ...however, 15 years and 6 months ago, Microsoft Bob was born.

Answer (score 12):

If you can't think of a good name on a variable or function, you either don't understand what you're doing or you got a poor design. Either way, slapping some arbitrary name like "x" (unless you're dealing with coordinates) won't solve your dilemma; it will only make it worse and the pain to maintain greater.

Comment: I disagree. Developers won't always have a full understanding of the business's terminology. Heck, even the client may not be able to convey the terminology during requirements gathering-- let alone at times even understand their own business! But this doesn't stop software from being produced. It doesn't stop prototypes from being created. Or even code being out right thrown out because of a lack of understanding. But code in these situations still need to be produced and delivered.

Comment: @sunpech Excuse me, but this is a little scary. Are you trying to tell us that it's common to write random code not knowing what it actually does? If you don't know something, put some effort to find out and you'll avoid problems in the future.

Comment: @AdamByrtek No, I don't mean that. What I'm saying is that it's not always up to the developer and team to have the best understanding of what a client wants. Some clients have a hard time explaining what it is they want, or don't know what it is they want. Bad code does happen. Problems happen in projects from bad requirements to unrealistic deadlines. That's reality. There is no perfect world where a developer will have all unknowns resolved, where clients are perfect, and deadlines are accurate. Code generated for prototypes are meant to be thrown out. But coding still needs to happen.

Comment: continued... We're not talking about making production code or the final code just before a check-in. We're talking about how to name something that we don't have the fullest understanding of just yet-- to get started initially on something that is unclear for possibly a good reason (example: nobody on the team understands it yet, maybe not even the client).  But things need to move forward still based on what is known.

Comment: @sunpech: If you don't know what your business logic will be, throwing random variables around will still not solve a thing. What you _want_ to do in such a case is design a framework in which you can modify your business logic without having to rewrite the whole program (or at least get away with just tweaking it a bit). Building your entire system around a business logic which you do not understand or is unknown will only lead to disaster. Unless you're lucky and happen to hit the correct business logic. And programmers should not rely on luck-driven development.

Comment: Sorry, but -1. Sometimes, if i have programmers block, i simply can't think of a descriptive name for a variable despite having a tight grasp on what exactly it is i'm doing. It's one of the quirks of my brain :P

Comment: If you know exactly what the variable is for, you should be able to spell it out, e.g. "It is used to store [this]"; "It is used when checking [this]"; "It is used when iterating over [this]", etc. If so, then the name of the variable is staring you in the face: `containsThis`, `isThis`, `currentThis`, etc., or whatever naming convention you choose to apply. Sure, you may not be able to come up with a _brilliant and perfect_ name, but at least you should be able to come up with something that conveys its purpose. One way or another. If not, you don't know exactly what it's used for.

Comment: @gablin We're not talking about building entire systems here. The OP posted, and the meaning behind this entire naming convention discussion is based it being *temporary*. The meaning and importance of a good descriptive name is deferred until later, when one can produce a meaningful name. Sometimes when a developer needs to develop a prototype, a proof of concept, a *good name* will not be available. Even formal requirements are unknown. Prototype code is very often thrown out. It's not final code or to be shared with everyone. It's code so a developer can move on to something more important.

Comment: @sunpech: Even if you're doing a prototype, the code does _something_. What you're describing sounds very close to what Adam Byrtek wrote in his comment. And if you follow Portman's recipe for naming, you should never have to resort to a name such as `temporary`, `will_be_renamed`, `fksdjadfkasdf`, etc.

Comment: @gablin There is a history behind foo and bar. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar The point is to defer the meaning until later. I'm not against coming up with a good name from the start, but if one cannot be made (as the OP is stating), then don't let that stop a developer from being productive. Put a placeholder name in, make a comment like: '// TODO: rename variable ', move on, get work done. Be careful of when you say *never have to resort to a name such as temp*. Even Jon Skeet has issues coming up with a good name (see OP comment link).

Comment: @sunpech: The only place I've actually seen `foo` and `bar` be used in code is in small snippets of code used to show a concept. Sure, I stumble too when think up names, but I have never ended up in such bad position where `foo` has been the only reasonable option. If that were to happen, then I really don't know what the hell I'm doing and need to go back to the drawing board and pseudo-code instead till I know what to do.

Comment: @sunpech: By the way, I think we're reaching the longest comment-based discussion ever on this site. ^^

Answer (score 5):

This question and especially its answers scare me senseless. Somebody's going to have to maintain that code in which you just named a variable "Cup", you know. If you're not lucky, that somebody will be you!

You've got a variable. It's a thing. It represents a thing, anyway. And things have names. *That's how you know they're things!* Are you really telling me you have to name a thing after another thing because you can't come up with the name of the actual thing?

Iterators should be called i. Nested iterators are likely a mistake, but if you need them, then make your way through the rest of the vowels, in order (a, e, o, u, and god help me, yes, sometimes y).

Apart from that, just call the thing what it is and be done with it!

Comment: I must protest! Clearly the inner iterator should be called _j_ and the one inside that _k_. Long-standing mathematical tradition is looking over your shoulder!

Comment: Huh. I've never done j and k. I see that it's sensible, though.

Comment: One reason Dijkstra was such a natural fit for computer science was that his name included the three commonest iterator variables in the right order.

Comment: @glenatron: Finally, a way to remember how to spell that name!

Answer (score 4):

If I can't come up with a great name right away, I use an "okay" name temporarily, then keep coding. At least it'll be something that *adequately* describes the item, even it's not *perfect*. Almost always, by the time I'm done writing the first draft of that particular chunk of code, a more perfect name will have occurred to me. Through the process of coding, my intentions with that particular variable become more clear. (On the other hand, sometimes it occurs to me that the variable to was ill-conceived to begin with and I delete it in favor of something else.)

Answer (score 3):

I name it what I think the function should do -- something that more or less conveys the intent. Once the body of the function is written, I find it obvious what to call it and go back and rename it if needed.

Comment: This doesn't always work, especially when the developer may not be familiar with the terminology or even intent of the business/industry.  Something more generic and obvious should be used to convey that it needs to be defined and changed later on.  The OP seems to be asking when the intent is unknown, and what should *initially* be used.  If the naming is something that more or less conveys intent, then a good name is already not far off.

Comment: @sunpech Seriously, even when first starting out in a job with a fairly specific domain, I haven't had trouble coming up with a function name. Maybe I just need to write more functions. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Maybe I've just been unlucky. Too often I have function names where even the acronyms are long. Example: CalculateHPQRZ(). Or classes where I have to use a medical dictionary to look up what exactly the name means. :)

Comment: @sunpech: How can you write a function without knowing what it does?

Comment: @sunpech: And long names are bad? Tell that to `getListCellRendererComponent`

Comment: @configurator Have you ever seen functions in code named Step1(), Step2(), Step3()...? They work and they do what's necessary. Do they describe exactly what is being done? No. Is it good clean code? No. Is it good enough to get things started, to realize a prototype, to then start editing once more is known? Yes. -- I'm saying bad code happens, it's necessary at times. No one writes great code from the get-go. It all starts somewhere based on probably bad requirements and understanding, and it needs to get where it should to be improved. Yes, I'm a fan of duct tape programming.

Comment: @sunpech: No, I've never seen functions called Step1(), Step2(), Step3(). Or a reason to create them. If I know what the step is going to be, I have a name for it. If I don't, I can't write it anyway. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @configurator Well, those were examples. I personally don't write code like that, but I've had team members that have. It's unfortunate. Bad code happens, business moves forward.

Comment: @sunpech: I think I've lost track of the discussion here. Was the original question "how to write bad code"? Are you saying that developers should create bad code because it happens anyway?

Comment: @configurator A lot of people seem to imply that naming a function/variable shouldn't happen until the developer fully understands everything. I'm saying that's not realistic, especially when prototyping. I'm saying that sloppy code happens (name a function DoFoo(), name a variable foobar, etc). They aren't ideal. As a business, there are bigger things at play other than making pretty code. Don't let small things get in the way of achieving the larger task at hand. Rename the function/variable names later.

Comment: @sunpech: I didn't say that. I just said you can't possibly write  a function without knowing what it's doing. It's not possible. I've never seen it happen, and I don't see how it could possibly happen. Maybe I'm being daft, but when you name a function DoFoo(), what in the hell do you put inside it??

Comment: @configurator: Exactly. At least with something like Step1(), Step2(), you can imagine that maybe they're responsible for stuff in a wizard dialog (hopefully!). But DoFoo()? Abracadabra()? I don't get it.

Comment: @configurator @AnnaLear There are so many ways to write software. Top-Down. Bottom-Up. Middle-Out. Why would assume that you must first define the name of what you're doing before you do anything? Maybe you need to do a bunch of *stuff*, and slowly pull together the details into the high level names that are more meaningful. Where do you think foo and bar came from? They don't have meaning and aren't important yet, that's the point. See Wiki on Foobar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: @sunpech: Explain this situation to me. You're about to write a function that does `X`. You don't know what `X` is, so you can't name the function. How are you going to know what to put inside it then?

Comment: @sunpech: Unless you're programming by randomly selecting different code tokens and hoping that it will somehow do what you wanted, I don't see how that can happen.

Comment: @configurator You're again, assuming you want to write a function first, and fill in what the function does after you named it. That's not the only way to write code. Sometimes there's code that you've inherited, a series of specific business steps, which isn't easily described by your business analyst. You want to modularize it because it's used again and again. You make a function, call it DoFoo() *temporarily* because there is no good name that you can think of....

Comment: Why Foo? Because it's a popular meaningless name in the coding community. Add a comment like '// TODO: Rename. Need further clarification'. Put the code into it, move on to something more important until you can properly name it. Keyword of the OP, **TEMPORARY**. Code isn't holy or sacred. It can be changed, cleaned up , and corrected later on. And we're not talking about code that's going to be shared or checked-in. It's probably code so the developer can move onto more important things rather than get wrapped up on making code pretty and easy to read.

Comment: **foo** and **bar** are popular if you come from outside the Microsoft culture. From what I've seen, mostly devs with Unix background use it. Devs that have written perl scripts etc.

Comment: @configurator also, no one said anything about random tokens. The keyword has always been *temporary* and the OP said *place-card*, so it's meant to be corrected later on. We're not talking about coding by luck or randomly, the meaning of this entire question is about making something good enough and searchable to be corrected later on when better information is available. I think this whole notion that code should be named correctly from the start is so far off from the intention of what the question is on. There's a difference between 'good enough for me now' and 'good enough for everyone'.

Comment: @sunpech: I never said names have to be 'good' from the start. I just fail to see how you would come into a situation where you want to create a function but you don't know what it's going to do.

Answer (score 2):

**foo** and **bar**.  Since there's no meaning behind naming functions/variables just yet, I use some combination of Foo and/or Bar with whatever I'm trying to define.

It makes it easy to search/find later on when I do have a better understanding of what it should be named.

Also see [Foobar on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).

> The terms foobar, foo, bar, and baz are sometimes used as placeholder names (also referred to as metasyntactic variables) in computer programming or computer-related documentation. They have been used to name entities such as variables, functions, and commands whose purpose is unimportant and serve only to demonstrate a concept. The words themselves have no meaning in this usage. Foobar is sometimes used alone; foo, bar, and baz are sometimes used in that order, when multiple entities are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your function with something and give it a best-shot name for now. For example, a function that saves-all-products-for-the-selected-user-to-the-database could be `RENAME_SaveAllProductsForTheSelectedUserToTheDatabase`()

Comment: Of course, in this case, you should just name the function `SaveAllProductsForTheSelectedUserToTheDatabase()`

Answer (score 1):

Whatever I call these hard to name variables I make a  `//TODO find a better name` comment so I can go back later to rename it

Usually, when I start to use  the variable/function/class I find a better name for them.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to put a good name in soon while you have the code in mind, than to wait until later when you'll be wishing you had named it well!

Answer (score 0):

I almost never have a problem finding good, descriptive names.. but sometimes the naming becomes quite redundant, in that the class and variable names ar very similar.
    WebClient webclient = new Webclient (uri );
...and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use zzzz temporarily.

A good rule to help you is this:

- Does it return a boolean and have no side effects: Then use an adjective (start with is, was) but never future tense.
- Does it return a different type and have no side effects: Then use a noun.
- Does it return nothing but do something: Then use a verb.
- Is it a class: Then use a noun.

Answer (score -1):

In the past I used **bob** a lot, but this would be the only not-properly-named variable in the function/script because otherwise the code quickly gets unreadable.

(bob is a hangover from uni days - getting away with calling variables bob and fred)

I'm happy to use **i** for a counter.

Better to use meaningful names, even if they're not short and snappy.

Comment: I've worked with a guy who used names like that for his applications and classes within his applications.  Perhaps needless to say, his code was generally very poor.

Comment: @dash-tom-band: I'd think his code was generally very bob.

Comment: If I can work my name into some hungarian notation for an enumeration I usually do it, even if it's a bit of a stretch. TPropertyEnhancmentTypeEditor = (PETEObtuse, PETEAwful, PETEDispicable);

Answer (score -1):

If I absolutely have no idea what to name the variable, which hasn't happened in over twenty years...names of old girlfriends, or women I wish had been girlfriends.  The last code with those identifiers was removed from production quite a few years ago.

Answer (score -2):

WorkMagic or Abracadabra.

Answer (score -2):

**blah**, but only temporarily.  I always go back and rename them to good variable names.

Comment: _Never_ use this. No. Bad.

Answer (score -2):

Doit(), a(), b(c) xxxx()....

Of course they get refactored away ....usually

Answer (score -3):

I tend to use stuff on my desk.

- Cup
- Alt
- Foo
- b / a / c (single letter junk)
- alk (pronounceable multi-letter junk)

I also lean towards generic names (for functions at least):

- swap
- process
- reviseVar
- tinker

This is for temporary stuff though. I *swear* nothing makes it into the repository, much less production.

> ...

Comment: I always feel dirty, but sometimes the most apparent name for a method is "Go" or "DoIt".  Whenever I can come up with a better name I do, but sometimes it really is "do the work that the name of the program implies is about to occur."  That, however, is too long to use for a function name.  :)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: For some reason, `run` looks much better than `go`. Maybe it's because we'd all like our programs to be faster.